# Using Distance Formula to Graph and Find Equation

Tags: calculus

My Question : Write an equation for the plane which passes
through the point P(3, 1,−2) and satisfies the given condition.
Parallel to the xy-plane.

How does one use the equation : $$(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2 + (z − c)^2 = r^2$$

In order to find the answer. I understand how to graph in x,y,z. But I do not understand how to find the answer algebraically. Do you just fill in the blanks like this $$ (x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2+ (z+2)^2 = r^2$$

Comment: Why do you refer to the equation of a sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plane which is parallel to the xy plane has normal parallel to the z axis.
So the plane is $z=-2$

Comment: What is the equation you used to find the answer?

Comment: The equation of a plane through $\underline{a}$ and with normal $\underline{n}$ is $\underline{r}\cdot\underline{n}=\underline{a} \cdot\underline{n}$